# UITabbarItem - remove the highlighting shadow

Tags: iphone, background, highlighting, uitabbaritem

I have been looking for an answer to this, but neither SO nor the web seem to have this covered ( I surely oversaw something...).

I would like to remove the shadow of a highlighted UITabBarItem - the one with the rounded edges. I already have custom images for each item and a custom image for the UITabBar. I looked into the UITabBarItem class but found no property for it....

What do I have to look for / does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITabBarItem only take a mask for its icon and generate himself the normal and hilighted state. You can not change this.

If you really want a UITabBarItem different you will have to reimplement everyghting.

Comment: i feared so. made a workaround. hack rather. am not happy. thanks tho'!